# Add CTRL-Click on XML Document using Visual Studio 2010 SDK

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, sdk

I have an XML file in the following format:

```
<Document>
  <Bars>
    <Bar id="1">
      <Name>test</Name>
    </Bar>
    <Bar id="2">
      <Name>test</Name>
    </Bar>
  </Bars>

  <Foo>
    <Bar>1</Bar>
    <Bar>2</Bar>
  </Foo>
</Document>
```

Now what I want to do is add a CTRL+Click functionality on for example "1", which moves the cursor to the correct "Bar" tag.
Does anybody know how to add the CTRL + Click functionality on an xml tag to fire an event, using the Visual Studio SDK?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166217.aspx

Which classes are needed, where do I start?

Comment: Are you saying you are creating an Xml editor or using the VS editor?

Comment: I'm using the VS editor but want to add CTRL+Click functionality to move from an xml tag to another.